# Do I need to create new app id for each app I want to track installs?

Tags: android, facebook-apps

I have created a app install app in Facebook to track install of my android game. It's working fine but it seems that if I re-install the game, Facebook doesn't track it anymore.

Could it be because the Facebook App Id is now linked on my phone for this game? Do I need to create a app id for each game that I want to track installs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want events [including installs] reported separately in Facebook's Analytics UI, you need a different app ID for each 'app' (you can share the same app ID for the same app on Android/iOS)

The events sent by your apps are stored based on the Facebook app ID used, so if you share an app ID across disparate apps, the stats get lumped together and won't be (as?) useful for analysis